# Beautifulsoup find_all does not find all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, findall

I am currently working on a webcrawler. I want my code to grab the text from all of the urls I crawled. Function getLinks() finds the links i want to grab data from and puts them into an array. The array is currently filled with 12 links like this one: 
*'http://www.computerstore.nl/product/142504/category-100852/wd-green-wd30ezrx-3-tb.html'*

And here is the code of my function that loops over my array with the urls i got from `getLinks()`, and grabs data from it. So the problem i ran into is that it sometimes returns the text 6 times, sometimes 8 or 10. But not 12 times as it should.

```
def getSpecs(): 
    i = 0 
    while (i < len(clinks)):
        r = (requests.get(clinks[i]))
        s = (BeautifulSoup(r.content))
        for item in s.find_all("div", {"class" :"productSpecs roundedcorners"}):
            print item.find('h3')
        i = i + 1 

getLinks()
getSpecs()
```

How do I fix this? Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why have `i` or `j` and a `while` loop at all instead of `for url in curl:`?

Comment: Also, why assign `item` before overwriting that initial assignment by reusing it as an iterator?

Comment: Also, if the problem is with `getSpecs`, not `getLinks`, you could give us *only* `getSpecs` and an example of a URL returned by `getLinks`, and your question would be far smaller and better-focused.

Comment: It would, by the way, be far better form to have `getLinks` return a new list of URLs rather than modifying a global variable.

Comment: ...personally, my guess is that the `class` you're getting is not *exactly* the string `productSpecs roundedcorners` in one of the cases handled; perhaps it's `roundedcorners productSpecs`, or `productSpecs roundedcorners somethingElse`.

Comment: (Not that that's the only possibility; could be that you're relying on DOM manipulation happening in JavaScript or otherwise browser-side to get the expectation of retrieving 12 items, to throw out another possibility. Which is to say that it's the overwhelming likelihood, and true in every question of this form I've yet seen, that BeautifulSoup is behaving to spec, but there's a misunderstanding around reasonable expectations for its behavior).

Comment: The class is the same string on every link. So that is not the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the improved code with multiple fixes:

- use [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) maintained throughout the the script life cycle
- use [`urparse.urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) to join URL parts
- use [`CSS selectors`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead of `find_all()`
- improved the way products are being found on the page
- transformed index-based loops into *pythonic* loops over list items

The code:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base_url = 'http://www.computerstore.nl'
curl = ["http://www.computerstore.nl/category/100852/interne-harde-schijven.html?6437=19598"]

session = requests.Session()
for url in curl:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).content)
    links = [urljoin(base_url, item['href']) for item in soup.select("div.product-list a.product-list-item--image-link")]

    for link in links:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(link).content)
        print soup.find('span', itemprop='name').get_text(strip=True)
```

It grabs every product link, follows it and prints out the product title (12 products):

```
WD Red WD20EFRX 2 TB
WD Red WD40EFRX 4 TB
WD Red WD30EFRX 3 TB
Seagate Barracuda ST1000DM003 1 TB
WD Red WD10EFRX 1 TB
Seagate Barracuda ST2000DM001 2 TB
Seagate Barracuda ST3000DM001 3 TB
WD Green WD20EZRX 2 TB
WD Red WD60EFRX 6 TB
WD Green WD40EZRX 4 TB
Seagate NAS HDD ST3000VN000 3 TB
WD Green WD30EZRX 3 TB
```